# Is indirect casting unsupported when calling functions?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

When you cast from A to B it's easy via constructors and casting operators. But when you have a "middleman", a 3rd type in between it works with constructor initialization or even when equating one type with the other, but parameter passing in a function call doesn't seem to work.

My question: is it an unsupported thing in C++ or do I miss something? See my 3 comments in the code below. (I'm using VS2015 update 3's compiler)

```
class StringOut
{
public:
    char* ptr = nullptr;
    StringOut() {}
    operator char*() { return ptr; }
};

class StringIn
{
public:
    char* ptr = nullptr;
    StringIn() {}
    StringIn(char* ptr) { StringIn::ptr = ptr; }
    void operator=(char* ptr) { StringIn::ptr = ptr; }
    //StringIn(StringOut& ptr) { StringIn::ptr = ptr.ptr; }
};

void ff1(StringIn strin)
{

}

void ff1(int a)
{

}

void ff()
{
    StringOut strout;
    StringIn strin = strout; // compiles
    strin = strout; // compiles

    ff1(strout); // doesn't compile
};
```

Certainly, if I use the commented out code, I'll work. But my question is if it's a limitation of C++ that I need a direct operator like this, or do I miss something?

Comment: Surely the compiler said more than "doesn't compile".

Comment: What is the basis for your belief that a 'middleman' cast works in constructor initialization? It isn't demonstrated by anything here.

Comment: A code such as `StringIn strin = strout;` is a constructor type initialization, and equivalent with `StringIn strin(strout);`

Comment: Still not demonstrated. That's only one step. It doesn't involve a man-in-the-middle type. C++ will only take one step, in all circumstances. There aren't special rules for special places about this AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic conversions are only done 'one step'. Allowing it two step would not only make the compiler's work extremely difficult if not unmanageable - you quickly run into too many variations and it is unclear which one to choose, but also makes it pretty much ununderstandable for humans what happens.

So yes, it is an intentional limitation in the language definition.

Comment: Actually, I'm happy about this limitation, I just wanted to double check. Thank you for the answer!